# Can singleton value be changed and assign to null

Tags: design-patterns, singleton

If I create a singleton and have only one instance of its creation. If I have a forloop where I assign the value of singleton to null and try to access this value in next iteration it would break. Is it advisable to change the value of singleton? If yes, what scenarios?

Comment: Add sample code and goal that you try to achieve to the question, please

Comment: If you need to dispose of an instance and then subsequently create new instances, then the Singleton Pattern doesn't sound appropriate for you. It's unclear what you are trying to achieve - be more descriptive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One disadvantage of Singleton Pattern is that it’s hard to test a class which calls the singleton since you cannot mock it.

However, if you make the scope of the `instance` to be `package`, you can mock it by assigning the `instance` to whatever you want. This is the only use case where re-assigning a singleton makes sense.

Please refer to this article https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2015/07/01/TheLittleSingleton.html for more details.